# FATAL EXCEPTION: main in android app

Tags: android

I am very new in developing an android app and programming in JAVA. I am trying to develop this app that I was in the understanding that at least will show me the user interface, but I keep getting the problem of a faltal exception: main?... can you please help me?

This is the activity main in xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Lights"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/Lights"
        android:textColor="@style/AppBaseTheme" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/SysOff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/BluetoothConn"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:text="@string/SysOff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/SysOn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/SysOff"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/SysOff"
        android:text="@string/SysOn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/DoorsOpen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/DoorsClose"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/DoorsClose"
        android:onClick="DoorsOpen"
        android:text="@string/DoorsOpen" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/DoorsClose"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/SysOn"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/SysOn"
        android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
        android:onClick="DoorsClose"
        android:text="@string/DoorsClose" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BluetoothConn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Lights"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Lights"
        android:onClick="BTConnect"
        android:text="@string/BluetoothConnect" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/SysPwr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/SysOn"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/DoorsClose"
        android:text="@string/SysPwr" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/lightsOff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/LightsOn"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LightsOn"
        android:onClick="LightsOff"
        android:text="@string/LightsOff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Doors"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/DoorsOpen"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Lights"
        android:text="@string/Doors"
        android:textAppearance="@style/AppBaseTheme" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/LightsOn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/BluetoothConn"
        android:layout_below="@+id/BluetoothConn"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:onClick="LightsOn"
        android:text="@string/LightsOn" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.mustangsound;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void BTConnect (){

}

public void LightsOn (){

}

public void LightsOff (){

}

public void DoorsOpen (){

}

public void DoorsClose (){

}

public void SysOn (){

}

public void SysOff (){

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mustangsound"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" 
    android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mustangsound.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And the LogCat:

```
01-25 05:30:28.128: W/dalvikvm(1902): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught     exception (group=0xb4cf5908)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mustangsound/com.example.mustangsound.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at com.example.mustangsound.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     ... 11 more
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     ... 24 more
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a ColorStateList (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060000 a=-1 r=0x7f060000}
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2074)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:342)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:775)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:449)
01-25 05:30:28.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     ... 27 more
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: what is in line number 12.

Comment: r u using Bluetooth in ur app?

Comment: The idea is for later add Bluetooth to control some motors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its probably caused by the line

```
android:textColor="@style/AppBaseTheme"
```

in your first `TextView` . It probably should be

```
android:textAppearance="@style/AppBaseTheme"
```

as in your last `TextView`